# IS something wrong with my side or my service provider , help please

Tags: internet, modem

I am subscribed to a 2Mb internet package—TMnet Streamyx in a box—and I have been experiencing

1. Slow speed; see picture below.
2. Internet suddenly shuts off but the DSL light is stable (this happens every 2 hours).
3. This is my modem Downstream and upstream readings.

---

```
                    Downstream    Upstream
 SNR Margin:        41.0          16.0      db
 Line Attenuation:  10.5           2.0       db
 Data Rate:         2048          512       kbps
 Attainable Rate:   11308         928       kbps
 POWER:             9.0           11.5      dbm
 CRC:               0             1
```

Let me know what is wrong and what should I do?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you're missing a DSL filter. Do you have anything else connected to the phone line? An alarm system? Cordless phone? Answering machine? I'll bet some device doesn't have a proper DSL filter.

Comment: yup there is a DSL filter , the main line (before this was connected to my house phone ) is connected to the DSL filter. The DSL filter splits one line to my modem and the other is to my house phone .

Comment: Are there any other devices connected to the phone line? Satellite receiver? Answering machine? FAX machine? TiVo box? Alarm system? Cordless phone? Have you moved any phones lately?

Comment: nope just the house phone and modem .

Comment: Maybe you are to far from telephone exchange(switchboard)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your speed is less than half the supported one and more than half for upload, which is common problem on DSLs.
What you can do is make sure that all your cables and connections are in perfect condition.

- You can replace phone cable by UTP (network) cable, you will have better signal.
- Also, the more connectors you have, the worse the signal gets.
  Try to have a single piece of continuous cable from your source to your DSL modem.
- Make sure all RJ connectors make proper contact.